# Converting jQuery using CakePHP's Javascript Helper

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having issues converting the following jQuery/AJAX call to CakePHP's JS Helper.

Here is what currently works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DatabaseServerId").bind("change", function (event) {
        var server_id = $("#DatabaseServerId").val();
        $.ajax({
            async:true, 
            dataType:"html", 
            evalScripts:true, 
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#DatabaseEnvironmentId").html(data);
            }, 
            url:"\/apsportal\/servers\/get_environments/"+server_id
            }
        );
    return false;
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Here is what I have thus far:

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#DatabaseServerId')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
$this->Js->get('#DatabaseServerId')->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(
            array('controller' => 'servers', 'action' => 'get_environments'),
            array(
                    'update' => '#DatabaseEnvironmentId',
                    'async' => true,
                    'type' => 'html',
                    'dataExpression' => true,
                    'evalScripts' => true,
                    'data' => $data,
            )
    )
);
```

The issue is that the parameter passed has an array key specified and narrows the usage of this action.

```
http://my.domain.com/servers/get_environments?data%5BDatabase%5D%5Bserver_id%5D=36
```

Since `server_id` is being used in other models, I would rather have this as generic as possible.

Note: I figure if I standardize to the JS Helper, if something changes in the future, I'll only have to change things once.

Comment: I wouldn't use the JsHelper because it has been removed in CakePHP 3.0: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#jshelper

Comment: Forget the JsHelper, directly write jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, I used raw jQuery instead of CakePHP's methods.